# Embedding content of an Iframe to another Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

I have a index.html file and a function in an external js (can not be modified)
file which gives the following output

```
 return iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('Video');
```

**please be advised the iframe  used in the above code is not in the index.html file and I am dealing with two different iframes**

I would like to use the return value of this function known as getVideo() as content for my other iframe (id ="myFrame")  which is on index.html

I have tried the following code but it is not showing the desired result.

```
var result = getVideo();
document.getElementById('myFrame').src = result;
```

Any suggestions would be helpful - The solution does not have to be an Iframe cause the aim is to be able to display return value of that function in some way on the index.html file -

Comment: For your code to work, the getVideo function should return a url. Can you change the external js file to return something like `return iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('Video').src;`? Or can you not access it at all?

Comment: Unfortunately cant get access to that file - in some way I need to display the return value of that file on index.html - does not have to be iframe but thats my preference